# How do I console log the jQuery UI's datepicker date in Unix timestamp format?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timestamp

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker (https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and I am looking for a way to console log the selected date in a Unix timestamp format. Currently if I use

```
let taskDueDate = $('#datePicker').datepicker( "getDate" )
```

I get the normal date format of

```
Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

How do I convert this to the Unix timestamp format on the client side? I am looking to achieve something like

```
let taskDueDate = $('#datePicker').datepicker( "getDate" ).datepicker('@')
```

where the '@' is for the Unix timestamp format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. It seems the `Date` object's numeric value is in milliseconds so it has to be divided by one thousand (1000) to get seconds, then `floor()` so to prevent overstating the number of seconds which would happen if using `round()`.

```
let taskDueDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker( "getDate" );
console.log(Math.floor(taskDueDate / 1000));
```

[Get the number of seconds since Unix epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Get_the_number_of_seconds_since_Unix_Epoch)

Comment: I just found out when I divide the getdate function by 1000 it converts it to unix timestamp mode.